# Cannot change the HTML table's column sizes despite of giving width

Tags: html, css, html-table, styling

I have a table which is set to ?

I need to change the size of the columns. These are the column names and I have set width to 30 and 70. but it doesn't change. It is now displaying as 50:50.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  align-content: center;
  width: 25px;
}

th {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

td {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 38px;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<table height="100">
  <tr>
    <th width="30">Control Name</th>
    <th width="70">Image</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could you please construct a table not just a th?

Comment: Its a table with  <table height="100">
      <tr>
        <th width="30">Control Name</th>
        <th width="70">Image</th>
      </tr>

Comment: `width` and `height` attributes on *any* elements have been deprecated 259 years ago, **do not use that**. Instead, use CSS.

Comment: What is `width="30"` and `width="70"` even supposed to mean? `%`? You cannot use `%` in those age-long deprecated attributes. Stop using those!

Comment: What's really odd is that you've used CSS to specify the width as `25px` for all `th` and `td` elements. Pick a place to define your width. And make the place you pick CSS.

Comment: How do I specify column width in css then? can anyone explain

Comment: And i Have many tables in the same page. Each one of it should have the same width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make classes and set them on your cells. You can probably name them better then I did in my example, but that is just a hint on how you can do it.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  align-content: center;
  width: 25px;
}

th {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

td {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 38px;
  align-content: center;
}

.cell-width-30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.cell-width-70 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<table height="100">
  <tr>
    <th class="cell-width-30">Control Name</th>
    <th class="cell-width-70">Image</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```